# how to make selected radio button as checked?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pageblocktable, radio-button

depending upon the selection of radio button it displays the selected row in differnt fields.[image]

the selected radio button disappears after the selected row splited.but i want the radio button selected.

vf:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="RadioButton" showheader="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="allcons" title="Available Contacts" mode="inlineedit" >
      <apex:datatable id="allcons" value="{!AllContacts}" var="allcon" cellpadding="2" border="2" >
        <apex:column headervalue="Set as Primary">
          <apex:actionsupport action="{!selectcon}" event="onclick" rerender="consel,allcons">
            <input type="radio" />
            <apex:param name="conid" value="{!allcon.Id}">
          </apex:param>
        </apex:actionsupport>
      </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Last Name">
          <apex:inputText value="{!allcon.LastName}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="First Name">
          <apex:inputText value="{!allcon.FirstName}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Email">
          <apex:inputText value="{!allcon.Email}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Phone">
          <apex:inputText value="{!allcon.Phone}"/>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:datatable>
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblock id="consel" title="Selected Contact">
      <apex:pageblocktable id="allcons" value="{!selectedContact}" var="selcon">
        <apex:column headervalue="Last Name">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!selcon.LastName}">
        </apex:outputfield>
      </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="First Name">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!selcon.FirstName}">
        </apex:outputfield>
      </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Email">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!selcon.Email}">
        </apex:outputfield>
      </apex:column>
        <apex:column headervalue="Phone">
          <apex:outputfield value="{!selcon.Phone}">
        </apex:outputfield>
      </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
  </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class RadioButton {

    public RadioButton(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    List < contact > selectcon;
    Public List < contact > getAllContacts() {
        List < contact > allcons = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone from Contact limit 5];
        return allcons;
    }
    Public void selectcon() {
        String selcontactid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('conid');
        Contact con = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone from Contact where Id = : selcontactid];
        selectcon = new List < contact > ();
        selectcon.add(con);
    }
    Public List < contact > getselectedContact() {
        return selectcon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your `<input type="radio">` tag is not bound to anything. If you would like it to maintain state, you should replace it with an `<apex:input>` with a value bound to a Ctrl property.